# Is there a way to sort a data frame column to plot the count of one value vs. all others collectively?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df with a `seller` column which is either Amazon or various 3rd party sellers. I want to get a count and a pie chart of sellers with one value being Amazon and the other collectively all of the 3rd party sellers.

I was able to do this by running a SQL query in Jupyter, saving the query as a df, and then creating a pie chart. 
[image]

I tried using `df['seller'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')` but this produces a pie chart of Amazon and each other seller individually, not as a sum. 
[image]

Is there a way to do this using Pandas and Matplotlib? Could groupby be used to create two categories?

Comment: `df['seller'].eq('Amazon.com').value_counts().plot.pie()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, it just plots the False value, which is one circle.

Comment: Of course you need to replace `'Amazon.com'` with the actual string that identify `Amazon` seller.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: df['seller'].eq('Amazon.com').value_counts().plot.pie(labels=['Amazon','Other']) gives the desired result. 
How can add the total counts of the two groups?

Comment: I was able to add percentages: df['seller'].eq('Amazon.com').value_counts(normalize=True).plot.pie(labels=['Amazon','Other'],autopct='%.2f')